# Como converter uma matriz JavaScript para matriz em PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, array, matriz

O sistema me dá uma matriz em JavaScript para trabalhar na página. Eu posso obter esta matriz com PHP, mas não sei como converter de JavaScript para PHP e trabalhar usando o PHP.

Este é um exemplo da matriz em JavaScript:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  var uCatsOut=[
    //['ID','ParentID','isSection','Name','Descr','URL','NumEntries']
    ['1','0','0','categoria A','Descrição da categoria A','/board/categoria_a/1','1'],
    ['2','0','0','Categoria B','Descrição da categoria B','/board/categoria_b/2','0']
  ];
</script>
```

Quero deixar assim:

```php
$categ = array(
    '0' => array('1','0','0','categoria A','Descrição da categoria A','/board/categoria_a/1','1'),
    '1' => array('2','0','0','Categoria B','Descrição da categoria B','/board/categoria_b/2','0'),
);
```

Comment: Creio que se você serializar em JSON usando JavaScript e de-serializar usando PHP você vai obter exatamente o que quer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do lado do JavaScript tens de serializar esse array. Podes usar o JSON.stringify assim:

```
JSON.stringify(uCatsOut);
// dá uma string -> '[["1","0","0","categoria A","Descrição da categoria A","/board/categoria_a/1","1"],["2","0","0","Categoria B","Descrição da categoria B","/board/categoria_b/2","0"]]'
```

Do lado do PHP tens de descodificar o JSON, podes usar o `json_decode`.

```
$json = '[["1","0","0","categoria A","Descrição da categoria A","/board/categoria_a/1","1"],["2","0","0","Categoria B","DescriÃ§Ã£o da categoria B","/board/categoria_b/2","0"]]';
$phpArray = json_decode($json, true);
var_dump($phpArray);
```

Que vai dar:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(7) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [3]=>
    string(11) "categoria A"
    [4]=>
    string(26) "Descrição da categoria A"
    [5]=>
    string(20) "/board/categoria_a/1"
    [6]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(7) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [3]=>
    string(11) "Categoria B"
    [4]=>
    string(30) "Descrição da categoria B"
    [5]=>
    string(20) "/board/categoria_b/2"
    [6]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
}
```

Comment: E, caso não esteja claro para o autor da pergunta, a passagem dos dados do JS para o PHP precisa ocorrer via Ajax ou envio de formulário.